# Can not read video in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I am having big trouble to read video using matlab in Ubuntu 16.04. When I try to read any format of video I get this error

```
Error using VideoFileReader/setup
Could not open the specified file.
```

I have installed all the gstreamer plugin to and I have changed `matlabroot/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6` with my `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`
Last time when I installed matlab in my Ubuntu system the above method solved the problem but this time no work. I need help.

Sometimes i used to get this error to:

```
Error using dspmmfileinfo>tryVideoReader (line 278)
Failed to initialize internal resources. The specified file is:
/home/mofiqul/repos-git/Image-Processing/matlab/multi-object-tracking/video4.avi

Error in dspmmfileinfo>getFileInfo (line 180)
           [hasAudio,hasVideo,videoFPSComputed,videoFramesPerSecond, ...
Error in dspmmfileinfo (line 40)
            cache.fileInfo(index) = {getFileInfo(filename)};

Error in vision.VideoFileReader/setFileInfoProps (line 349)

Error in vision.VideoFileReader/set.Filename (line 150)

Error in matlab.system.SystemProp/parseInputs (line 908)

Error in matlab.system.SystemProp/sysObjSetProperties (line 298)

Error in vision.VideoFileReader (line 133)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had fixed the issue. I was having missing plugins for gstreamer0.